# Query regarding Bit Counting (Python)

Tags: python, list, recursion

I tried to solve this Kata problem

Write a function that takes an integer as input, and returns the number of bits that are equal to one in the binary representation of that number. You can guarantee that input is non-negative.

Example: The binary representation of 1234 is 10011010010, so the function should return 5 in this case.

But the problem is my code gives the correct answers right for the first time around but when
it is run for 2nd time onward it gives wrong answers only. I think it has to do sth with how my code is recursive. Please help me figure it out.
for example when i run count_bits(24) it gives the output 2 which is correct but when i run the same function again it would give 4 and then 6 and so on . I dont know what's wrong with this

My code.

```
  dec_num = []

  def count_bits(n):
    
    def DecimalToBinary(n):
        if n >= 1:
            DecimalToBinary(n // 2)
        dec_num.append( n % 2)
        return dec_num
    
    dec = DecimalToBinary(n)
    
    return dec.count(1)
```

Comment: `dec_num` will still contains item from the first run.... so you need to set it back to an empty list... Also do you need to use recursion here... can you not just do `format(24, 'b').count('1')` ?

Comment: @JonClements yes I know there are predefined methods to convert decimal to binary format but I am trying to learn Python programming so I tried to do recursion . I also know there is .bin() method to convert decimal to python . Also if you have any feedback to improve i would appreciate

Comment: Alternatively, you could try this - ` str(bin(x)).count('1')`  as other way.

Comment: @DanielHao Or `x.bit_count()`.

Comment: @KellyBundy if you're on 3.10+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `dec_num` is outside the method, so it's reused at every call, put it inside

```
def count_bits(n):
    dec_num = []
    def DecimalToBinary(n):
        if n >= 1:
            DecimalToBinary(n // 2)
        dec_num.append(n % 2)
        return dec_num

    dec = DecimalToBinary(n)
    return dec.count(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a list of digits if all you need is their sum. When possible, avoid creating mutable state in a recursive solution:

```py
def count_bits(n):
    if n > 0:
        return n % 2 + count_bits(n // 2)
    else:
        return 0
```

That's a pretty natural translation of the obvious algorithm:

> The sum of the bits in a number is the last bit plus the sum of the bits in the rest of the number.

Sometimes it's convenient to accumulate a result, which is best done by adding an accumulator argument. In some languages, that can limit stack usage, although not in Python which doesn't condense tail calls. All the same, some might find this more readable:

```py
def count_bits(n, accum = 0):
    if n > 0:
        return count_bits(n // 2, accum + n % 2)
    else:
        return accum
```

In Python, a generator is a more natural control structure:

```
def each_bit(n):
    while n > 0:
        yield n % 2
        n //= 2

def count_bits(n):
    return sum(each_bit(n))
```

Of course, there are lots more ways to solve this problem.